# Set background color of parent div based on values of child span

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var kb_cards = document.querySelectorAll('div.kbCardContainer');
console.log("kb_cards length: " + kb_cards.length);
```

```html
<div class="row kbCardContainer">
    <span aria-live="assertive" role="alert" class="sr-only ng-binding"/>
    <!-- ngIf: !(isMobileView == 'true') -->
    <div class="col-md-12 ng-scope" ng-if="!(isMobileView == 'true')" style="">
        <!-- ngRepeat: knowledgeBase in knowledgeBases |filter:excludeAll -->
        <div class="kbCard ng-scope" role="none" tabindex="-1" ng-style="getStyle($index,knowledgeBase)" ng-click="clickKnowledgeBase(knowledgeBase)" ng-repeat="knowledgeBase in knowledgeBases |filter:excludeAll" style="border-left: 4px solid rgb(39, 142, 207);">
            <span role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Company AAA 19 Articles">
                <span class="kb-title kbCardOverflow ng-binding" aria-hidden="true">Company AAA</span>
                <span class="kb-card-details">
                    <!-- ngIf: knowledgeBase.enable_socialqa -->
                    <span class="kb-count ng-binding" aria-hidden="true"> 19 Articles</span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="kb-card-details" ng-init="subscribedLabel[knowledgeBase.sys_id] = 'Subscribed'">
                <!-- ngIf: !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
                <span ng-attr-id="subscribe{{knowledgeBase.sys_id}}" class="subscribe ng-scope" ng-if="!knowledgeBase.isSubscribed" ng-click="knowledgeBase.isSubscribed = !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed; clickSubscribe(knowledgeBase, $event)" role="button" aria-label="Subscribe to Company AAA" tabindex="0" id="subscribe47f9af20dbaae810b2fe3313f39619df">
                    <i class="icon-empty-circle"/>Subscribe</span>
                <!-- end ngIf: !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
                <!-- ngIf: knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
            </span>
        </div>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: knowledgeBase in knowledgeBases |filter:excludeAll -->
        <div class="kbCard ng-scope" role="none" tabindex="-1" ng-style="getStyle($index,knowledgeBase)" ng-click="clickKnowledgeBase(knowledgeBase)" ng-repeat="knowledgeBase in knowledgeBases |filter:excludeAll" style="border-left: 4px solid rgb(75, 215, 98);">
            <span role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Company ADB 0 Articles">
                <span class="kb-title kbCardOverflow ng-binding" aria-hidden="true">Company ADB</span>
                <span class="kb-card-details">
                    <!-- ngIf: knowledgeBase.enable_socialqa -->
                    <span class="kb-count ng-binding" aria-hidden="true"> 0 Articles</span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="kb-card-details" ng-init="subscribedLabel[knowledgeBase.sys_id] = 'Subscribed'">
                <!-- ngIf: !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
                <span ng-attr-id="subscribe{{knowledgeBase.sys_id}}" class="subscribe ng-scope" ng-if="!knowledgeBase.isSubscribed" ng-click="knowledgeBase.isSubscribed = !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed; clickSubscribe(knowledgeBase, $event)" role="button" aria-label="Subscribe to Company ADB" tabindex="0" id="subscribe83f9af20dbaae810b2fe3313f39619e6">
                    <i class="icon-empty-circle"/>Subscribe</span>
                <!-- end ngIf: !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
                <!-- ngIf: knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
            </span>
        </div>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: knowledgeBase in knowledgeBases |filter:excludeAll -->
        <div class="kbCard ng-scope" role="none" tabindex="-1" ng-style="getStyle($index,knowledgeBase)" ng-click="clickKnowledgeBase(knowledgeBase)" ng-repeat="knowledgeBase in knowledgeBases |filter:excludeAll" style="border-left: 4px solid rgb(255, 202, 31);">
            <span role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Company BBD 0 Articles">
            <span class="kb-title kbCardOverflow ng-binding" aria-hidden="true">Company BBD</span>
            <span class="kb-card-details">
                <!-- ngIf: knowledgeBase.enable_socialqa -->
                <span class="kb-count ng-binding" aria-hidden="true"> 0 Articles</span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="kb-card-details" ng-init="subscribedLabel[knowledgeBase.sys_id] = 'Subscribed'">
            <!-- ngIf: !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
            <span ng-attr-id="subscribe{{knowledgeBase.sys_id}}" class="subscribe ng-scope" ng-if="!knowledgeBase.isSubscribed" ng-click="knowledgeBase.isSubscribed = !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed; clickSubscribe(knowledgeBase, $event)" role="button" aria-label="Subscribe to Company BBD" tabindex="0" id="subscribe07f9af20dbaae810b2fe3313f39619e9">
                <i class="icon-empty-circle"/>Subscribe</span>
            <!-- end ngIf: !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
            <!-- ngIf: knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
        </span>
    </div>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: knowledgeBase in knowledgeBases |filter:excludeAll -->
</div>
<!-- end ngIf: !(isMobileView == 'true') -->
<!-- ngIf: (isMobileView == 'true') -->
</div>
```

In the snippet above, I have an extract of HTML from a Service Now Knowledge Base page.

When there are hundreds of KB categories, most of which have no articles against them, I wanted to work out how to add a style attribute to the divs with a class of `kbCard` so that e.g. the background is yellow.

I realise I could do something like this:

```
var this_card = document.querySelectorAll('div.kbCard');
var_name.setAttribute("style", "background:yellow;");
```

However, in this scenario, I need to loop through all of the `kbCard` divs nested below the parent `kbCardContainer` div, and from there, check the value of the `kb-count` span, and if it is not "0 Articles", then set the style attribute of the `kbCard` div.

I realise that's asking for a lot though!

I'm familiar with looping through records and updating them - e.g.

```
var table_cells = document.querySelectorAll('td.vt');
for (var j = 0; j < table_cells.length; j++) {
    var cell = table_cells[j];
    cell.innerHTML = cell.innerHTML.replaceAll('Work in Progress', 'WIP');
    cell.innerHTML = cell.innerHTML.replaceAll('Root Cause Analysis', 'RCA');
    cell.innerHTML = cell.innerHTML.replaceAll('Development', 'Dev');
}
```

But in this case, I am stuck on a number of fronts because:

1. The length of kbCardContainer is only returning 1 because there *is* only 1 div nested below it, with a class of `col-md-12`. I can't select on that class as there are other divs on the page with the same class. How can I select the contents of div `col-md-12` nested below the `kbCardContainer` div?
2. Even if I could fix 1, I'm not sure how to check the contents of a SPAN nested below another DIV, and then set an attribute of the parent DIV...

Sorry, I am asking for "the moon on a stick" here, but thought I'd ask for advice anyway.

Apologies for my mistakes etc.

Thanks

Comment: *I can't select on that class as there are other divs on the page with the same class.* [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is an element function and not an exclusive `document` function like `getElementById`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you want to do is to get all your cards, by doing something like it:

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".kbCard");
```

Then you will need to loop throw them, to do what you need:

```
for(card of cards) {
    let subChild = GetWantedSubchild(card);
    if (!subChild) continue;

    if (subChild.textContent.includes("0 Articles")) {
        // Do what ever you want
        card.setAttribute("style", "background:yellow;");
    }
}

function GetWantedSubchild(element) {
    let childLevel1 = element.children[0];
    if (!childLevel1) return undefined;

    return childLevel1.querySelector(".kb-card-details");
}
```

So now, how I created this GetWantedSubchild. I looked at the HTML structure you show us, and I tried to simplify it, by removing no "needed elements" (for our problem).

```
<div class="kbCard ng-scope">
    <span role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Company BBD 0 Articles">
        <span class="kb-title kbCardOverflow ng-binding" aria-hidden="true">Company BBD</span>
        <span class="kb-card-details">
            <span class="kb-count ng-binding" aria-hidden="true"> 1 Articles</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

So we have a `.kbCard` div, inside there is a span element with no class or anything that can help us to select it. So you want to get the first child of your `.kbCard` div:

```
let childLevel1 = element.children[0]; // "element" is the .kbCard div
```

This `childLevel1` is this node : `<span role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Company BBD 0 Articles">`. From that node, I take a look to the HTML. I see that the element you want (where "0 Articles" is written) has the class **kb-card-details**. So it will be easy to select it. So it exactly what I do with `childLevel1.querySelector(".kb-card-details");`. And with this element I can check the content (if it is "0 Articles"), and do a treatment if it is.

Please note that I made my answer to fast, so I missed a point, the real node I should select at the end is `.kb-count`. It is the real span containing the value. But because it is the only node, I guess it still works.

I made a test on my side and it seems working :) Do not hesitate if you have any question.

Comment: Amazing! That works - thank you very much Dylan. If you have time, would you mind explaining how that works please? I see the `GetWantedSubchild` function is key to how it works, but I am not sure I can explain the logic you've followed, as I would find it useful to understand how you solved it. Thanks again.

Comment: @4532066 Yes no problem, I will edit my answer trying to give you more details on that

Comment: Thanks again Dylan - I have a better understanding of that now. So clever that you worked it out :-) and kind that you helped me out!

Comment: @4532066 I am so sorry I submit the edit without finish it! So now there are all information I  could think about.

Please note that I made a mistake in my answer, so I tried to point it out at the end, I hope it will not confuse you.

Comment: Thanks again that is really very helpful indeed! I wish I could upvote your answer many times!

Comment: @4532066 No worries it is a pleasure! Unfortunately you cannot upvote many times my answer, BUT you can send me money ;) (just kidding of course)

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, as another way of fixing this, I worked out how to check the specific value of the `kb-count` span via the following:

```
var kb_cards = document.querySelectorAll(".kbCard");
for(var kb_card of kb_cards) {
    var article_count = kb_card.querySelectorAll("span")[3].innerHTML;
    console.log("article_count: " + article_count);
    if (article_count != " 0 Articles") {
        kb_card.setAttribute("style", "background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #eee, #eee 10px, #f1f1f1 10px, #f1f1f1 20px); border-left:4px solid black;");
    }
}
```

I can check the article count value (div.kbCard) and get the value of the 3rd span nested under div.kbCard parent (`div class="kbCard"... -> span role="button... -> span class="kb-card-details"... -> span class="kb-count"`).

```js
    var kb_cards = document.querySelectorAll(".kbCard");
    for(var kb_card of kb_cards) {
        var article_count = kb_card.querySelectorAll("span")[3].innerHTML;
    console.log("article_count: " + article_count);
        if (article_count != " 0 Articles") {
            kb_card.setAttribute("style", "background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #eee, #eee 10px, #f1f1f1 10px, #f1f1f1 20px); border-left:4px solid black;");
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="row kbCardContainer">
    <span aria-live="assertive" role="alert" class="sr-only ng-binding"/>
    <!-- ngIf: !(isMobileView == 'true') -->
    <div class="col-md-12 ng-scope" ng-if="!(isMobileView == 'true')" style="">
        <!-- ngRepeat: knowledgeBase in knowledgeBases |filter:excludeAll -->
        <div class="kbCard ng-scope" role="none" tabindex="-1" ng-style="getStyle($index,knowledgeBase)" ng-click="clickKnowledgeBase(knowledgeBase)" ng-repeat="knowledgeBase in knowledgeBases |filter:excludeAll" style="border-left: 4px solid rgb(39, 142, 207);">
            <span role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Company AAA 19 Articles">
                <span class="kb-title kbCardOverflow ng-binding" aria-hidden="true">Company AAA</span>
                <span class="kb-card-details">
                    <!-- ngIf: knowledgeBase.enable_socialqa -->
                    <span class="kb-count ng-binding" aria-hidden="true"> 19 Articles</span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="kb-card-details" ng-init="subscribedLabel[knowledgeBase.sys_id] = 'Subscribed'">
                <!-- ngIf: !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
                <span ng-attr-id="subscribe{{knowledgeBase.sys_id}}" class="subscribe ng-scope" ng-if="!knowledgeBase.isSubscribed" ng-click="knowledgeBase.isSubscribed = !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed; clickSubscribe(knowledgeBase, $event)" role="button" aria-label="Subscribe to Company AAA" tabindex="0" id="subscribe47f9af20dbaae810b2fe3313f39619df">
                    <i class="icon-empty-circle"/>Subscribe</span>
                <!-- end ngIf: !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
                <!-- ngIf: knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
            </span>
        </div>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: knowledgeBase in knowledgeBases |filter:excludeAll -->
        <div class="kbCard ng-scope" role="none" tabindex="-1" ng-style="getStyle($index,knowledgeBase)" ng-click="clickKnowledgeBase(knowledgeBase)" ng-repeat="knowledgeBase in knowledgeBases |filter:excludeAll" style="border-left: 4px solid rgb(75, 215, 98);">
            <span role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Company ADB 0 Articles">
                <span class="kb-title kbCardOverflow ng-binding" aria-hidden="true">Company ADB</span>
                <span class="kb-card-details">
                    <!-- ngIf: knowledgeBase.enable_socialqa -->
                    <span class="kb-count ng-binding" aria-hidden="true"> 0 Articles</span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="kb-card-details" ng-init="subscribedLabel[knowledgeBase.sys_id] = 'Subscribed'">
                <!-- ngIf: !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
                <span ng-attr-id="subscribe{{knowledgeBase.sys_id}}" class="subscribe ng-scope" ng-if="!knowledgeBase.isSubscribed" ng-click="knowledgeBase.isSubscribed = !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed; clickSubscribe(knowledgeBase, $event)" role="button" aria-label="Subscribe to Company ADB" tabindex="0" id="subscribe83f9af20dbaae810b2fe3313f39619e6">
                    <i class="icon-empty-circle"/>Subscribe</span>
                <!-- end ngIf: !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
                <!-- ngIf: knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
            </span>
        </div>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: knowledgeBase in knowledgeBases |filter:excludeAll -->
        <div class="kbCard ng-scope" role="none" tabindex="-1" ng-style="getStyle($index,knowledgeBase)" ng-click="clickKnowledgeBase(knowledgeBase)" ng-repeat="knowledgeBase in knowledgeBases |filter:excludeAll" style="border-left: 4px solid rgb(255, 202, 31);">
            <span role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Company BBD 0 Articles">
            <span class="kb-title kbCardOverflow ng-binding" aria-hidden="true">Company BBD</span>
            <span class="kb-card-details">
                <!-- ngIf: knowledgeBase.enable_socialqa -->
                <span class="kb-count ng-binding" aria-hidden="true"> 0 Articles</span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="kb-card-details" ng-init="subscribedLabel[knowledgeBase.sys_id] = 'Subscribed'">
            <!-- ngIf: !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
            <span ng-attr-id="subscribe{{knowledgeBase.sys_id}}" class="subscribe ng-scope" ng-if="!knowledgeBase.isSubscribed" ng-click="knowledgeBase.isSubscribed = !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed; clickSubscribe(knowledgeBase, $event)" role="button" aria-label="Subscribe to Company BBD" tabindex="0" id="subscribe07f9af20dbaae810b2fe3313f39619e9">
                <i class="icon-empty-circle"/>Subscribe</span>
            <!-- end ngIf: !knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
            <!-- ngIf: knowledgeBase.isSubscribed -->
        </span>
    </div>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: knowledgeBase in knowledgeBases |filter:excludeAll -->
</div>
<!-- end ngIf: !(isMobileView == 'true') -->
<!-- ngIf: (isMobileView == 'true') -->
</div>
```